# Has anyone got experience with UIAutomation for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios4, ui-automation

Greetings!

I am running iOS 4.1 on my iPhone 3GS.

I have a small test app that has a five segment segmented controller that is connected to a UIView (?). When one of the five segments is clicked, the picture changed in the IUView.

I am trying to automate this using UIAutomation using the following js script:

```
UIALogger.logStart("picChoice Test Started");

var mySegment = (UIAElementArray) segmentedControls() [2];

UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().mySegment.tap();
```

My script is failing with a syntax error when run through Instrument's Automation tool.

Has anyone any pointers (please excuse the poor pun) about how to script this properly?

TIA for any and all asistance!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is (did not test it):

```
UIALogger.logStart("picChoice Test Started");
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[2].tap();
```

Note that segmentedControls()[2] returns a element not an array and that in your use of segmentedControls there is no context to find the segmented controls.